# unable to init h2o. can somebody help me with it

Tags: h2o

Checking whether there is an `H2O` instance running at http://localhost:54321..... not found.

Attempting to start a local H2O server...

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
>   Starting server from
>   C:\Users\Ramakanth\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\h2o\backend\bin\h2o.jar
>   Ice root: c:\users\ramaka~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpeaff8n   JVM stdout:
>   c:\users\ramaka~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpeaff8n\h2o_Ramakanth_started_from_python.out
>   JVM stderr:
>   c:\users\ramaka~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpeaff8n\h2o_Ramakanth_started_from_python.err
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "C:\Users\Ramakanth\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\h2o\h2o.py", line 262,
>   in init
>       min_mem_size=mmin, ice_root=ice_root, port=port, extra_classpath=extra_classpath)   File
>   "C:\Users\Ramakanth\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\h2o\backend\server.py",
>   line 121, in start
>       mmax=max_mem_size, mmin=min_mem_size)   File "C:\Users\Ramakanth\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\h2o\backend\server.py",
>   line 317, in _launch_server
>       raise H2OServerError("Server process terminated with error code %d" % proc.returncode) h2o.exceptions.H2OServerError: Server process
>   terminated with error code 1

Comment: Your code? in what environment (python, or, R)? Windows or *unix? version of software (R/Python/Java/H2O)?  For example, x86 version of Java cannot initialise a h2o instance with more than 4G ram.

Comment: Python 2.7.14, windows -x64

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming "build 9.0.1+11" means Java 9, that is your problem: H2O currently only supports Java 7 or Java 8. This is the [ticket to follow for adding Java 9 support](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4956). In the meantime uninstall your current Java, then install Java 8.

**UPDATE:** It seems Java 9 is now supported, so upgrade to h2o 3.20 or later.

---

BTW, normally you should be giving a lot more information: which language you are using, what code you used to try and start H2O (or the commandline if you started it that way), what OS, what versions of Java, R, Python, etc., number of cores, amount of memory, etc.