# h2o.init() and machine learning

Tags: python, h2o

when run `h20.init()` raise error like this:

> `Checking whether there is an H2O instance running at http://localhost:54321 ..... not found.
>   Attempting to start a local H2O server...
>   ; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13+33, mixed mode, sharing)
>     Starting server from d:\python\lib\site-packages\h2o\backend\bin\h2o.jar
>     Ice root: C:\Users\NIEFAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4vq2d_7d
>     JVM stdout: C:\Users\NIEFAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4vq2d_7d\h2o_Niefangchao_started_from_python.out
>     JVM stderr: C:\Users\NIEFAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4vq2d_7d\h2o_Niefangchao_started_from_python.err
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "<ipython-input-2-95453bf1556d>", line 1, in <module>
>       h2o.init()
>     File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\h2o\h2o.py", line 278, in init
>       bind_to_localhost=bind_to_localhost)
>     File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\h2o\backend\server.py", line 138, in start
>       bind_to_localhost=bind_to_localhost, log_dir=log_dir, log_level=log_level)
>     File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\h2o\backend\server.py", line 346, in _launch_server
>       raise H2OServerError("Server process terminated with error code %d" % proc.returncode)
>   H2OServerError: Server process terminated with error code 1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to init h2o. can somebody help me with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48208691/unable-to-init-h2o-can-somebody-help-me-with-it)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, replace JAVA10 with JAVA8